# Do I need Blend For Visual Studio If I have newest Visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I don't know the details, but when I tried **Blend For Visual Studio** it was such impression as **Blend** is just Visual Studio only with UWP support. If it so, the Blend should not be in my PC. It is really useless?

I also don't see **Blend For Visual Studio** among installed files. It was installed automatically with Visual Studio...

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that a company has different developers for frontend and backend. While the backend developer implements some client server communication in Visual Studio, the frontend developer creates custom controls and animations in Blend. Both work in parallel. Some of the functionality of blend has been ported to the visual studio designer, however you can do a lot of additional UI related work in blend. It is therefore only useless if the company you are working for is developing the UI and the code that powers the UI sequentially.